# GridSearchCV not working?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use grid search to figure out the best value for n_components to use in PCA:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


pca = PCA()
pipe_lr = Pipeline([('pca', pca),
                    ('regr', LinearRegression())])

param_grid = [{'pca__n_components': range(2, X.shape[1])}]

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_lr, 
                  param_grid=param_grid, 
                  cv=3)
gs = gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(gs.best_score_)
print(gs.best_params_)

for i in range(2, X.shape[1]):
    pca.n_components = i
    pipe_lr = pipe_lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print i, pipe_lr.score(X_test, y_test)
```

However, the results I am seeing are very weird (the numbers I get from the for loop are completely different from the ones from the grid search):

```
-0.232877626581
{'pca__n_components': 2}
2 0.0989156092429
3 0.258170750388
4 0.26328990417
5 0.263620889601
6 0.315725901097
7 0.315477694958
8 0.330445632512
9 0.328779889242
10 0.323594949214
11 0.322914495543
12 0.324050681182
13 0.334970652728
14 0.334333880177
15 0.335040376094
16 0.330876375034
17 0.335395590901
18 0.335132468578
19 0.331201691511
20 0.337244411372
21 0.337130708041
22 0.333092723232
23 0.340707011134
24 0.344046515328
25 0.337869318771
26 0.332590709621
27 0.345343677247
28 0.344728264973
29 0.343084912122
30 0.340332251028
31 0.34012312844
32 0.340290453979
33 0.340349696151
34 0.337021304382
35 0.327271480372
36 0.334423097757
37 -5.09330041094e+21
38 -5.06403949113e+21
```

According to the for loop, the best value for n_components should be around 28, but this is not even close to what I get from grid search

Note: I did not include the steps for setting up the train and test sets, but i used `train_test_split` from sklearn.

Answer (score 5):

`GridSearchCV`, spits out a **cross_validation** score. Adding a `cross_validation` to your for loop may give you a closer result.

Besides you are using different data. You have mentioned that you used `train_test_split`. In your for loop, you got the scores on X_test, y_test. In `GridSearchCV` you got a mean score on X_train, y_train. You might have outliers in your test set.

I slightly modified your code and applied it to the Boston data set.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score


boston = load_boston()
X = boston.data
y = boston.target

pca = PCA()
pipe_lr = Pipeline([('pca', pca),
                    ('regr', LinearRegression())])

param_grid = {'pca__n_components': np.arange(2, X.shape[1])}

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_lr, 
                  param_grid=param_grid, 
                  cv=3)
gs = gs.fit(X, y)
print(gs.best_score_)
print(gs.best_params_)


all_scores = []
for i in range(2, X.shape[1]):
    pca.n_components = i
    scores = cross_val_score(pipe_lr,X,y,cv=3)
    all_scores.append(np.mean(scores))
    print(i,np.mean(scores))

print('Best result:',all_scores.index(max(all_scores)),max(all_scores))
```

gives:

```
0.35544286032
{'pca__n_components': 9}
2 -0.419093097857
3 -0.192078129541
4 -0.24988282122
5 -0.0909566048894
6 0.197185975618
7 0.173454370084
8 0.276509863992
9 0.355148081819
10 -17.2280089182
11 -0.291804450954
12 -0.281263153468
Best result: 7 0.355148081819
```